# How to Handle Exceptions in Custom Library

Tags: java

I've been writing my personal library and I've been trying to implement this code I used in another program:

```
public ImagePanel(String imgpath) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgpath));
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Because this code is being added to a library, I'll want to handle the exception in new code I use this in.

Is this how I should properly implement this same code to my library?

```
public ImagePanel(String imgpath) throws IOException {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgpath));
}
```

And this being how I'd use my library in another program?

```
import testlib.ImagePanel;
ImagePanel boardPanel = null;
try {
    ImagePanel boardPanel = new ImagePanel("imageexample.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// do stuff here (boardPanel is "null" above because I've gotten an error that it's not initialized as I do that in the try/catch block)
```

Comment: That approach certain works. However, there are some arguments against throwing Exceptions from constructors. It may be better to separate the object instantiation from the invocation of the read/retrieval of the image, and add a `getImage(String imgpath) throws IOException` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle it IMO would be to wrap the IOException in an Error (ie `new Error(e)` and throw the Error. Again, IMO this is justified because the file being there or not really needs a runtime, not a compile time fix. And this way you wouldn't have to declare the Exception in the constructor, like

```
public ImagePanel(String imgpath) {
  try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgpath));
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: or use `RuntimeException` which is also unchecked.

Comment: How would you suggest wrapping the IOException? Catching it in my library's code and throwing a `new Error`?

Comment: @Aaron I've updated my answer to show how I'd do it

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks, that's how I thought I should do it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can return null if exception happens. It won't crash the program.

But when you 'throw' exception, it may crash the program if user doesn't 'catch' it.

```
public ImagePanel(String imgpath) throws IOException{
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(imgpath));
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
    throw new IOException();
    }
}
```